# Correlation between two samples of different size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, mean, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have all price quotes from a stock (to be more precisely CSAN3 from Ibovespa Exchange - Brazil) from 2010 to 2015. I was asked **to get the correlation from the log returns year-by-year.** This is unclear for me. But I want to make some analysis anyway. What I've done up to now was to get all log returns from 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013 and 2014. What I want now is to compare all these log returns. My first thought was to get the correlation year by year (correlation between 2010 and 2011, 2011 and 2012 and so on). However, each year has a specific number of working days, this results in different samples from each year. E.g. In 2010 I have 250 log returns (comparison was done day by day) and in 2011 I have 237 log returns. What do you guys think it's the best approach to infer something from this data? If the data was "number of t-shirts sold" for instance, how could I analyse and say that the number of t-shirts sold grows in may and decreases in august (I would like to try to assess something similar for the stocks)? Aside from that, how could I compare the gross values of the stocks between these years?
Summarizing, what I really want is to compare these samples and see how similar are the stock's behavior per year. How similar is the behavior (growth, decrease or values) between 2010 and 2011, 2011 and 2012 and so on?

The prior suggestions I have are:

1. Reduce the samples in order to get all the matching days and have all of them with the same number of log returns. So I would exclude the days that I have in 2010 and I don't have in 2011 and apply the `cor()` function from R.
2. Generate 1000 random samples of same size for both samples from 2010 and 2011 and apply the Wilcox test.
3. Do a hypothesis test for the mean.

What do you guys think?

Comment: What do you mean by "correlation" here? Do you want to see if the stock is higher on May 1 than June 2 in 2010, then it is comparable in 2011? Do you just want to estimate the degree of autocorrelation in the series?

Comment: Actually, that's part of the issue. I am not sure what does the question mean with correlation. What I think I need to do is to see the "behaviour" of the two samples. If both grow as the year is ending, or if both decrease. However, since the request is a little confuse, I thought about applying different strategies to analyse how similar are the two samples. So I guess part of my question is in what you've just asked. This is one of the things I want to find out

Comment: Have you plotted all the data in a way that you can compare the 6 years in question? Say, a plot with day of the year on the x axis, returns on the y axis, and a separate line connecting all the points for each single year? Sometimes a simple plot helps determine if there's anything worth examining to start with, and might point our a direction for detailed analysis.

Comment: You need to find that out from the people who asked you to do this. We can't tell you. & we may not be able to answer this question at all without knowing more about what the goal is.

Comment: @EdM I could plot. It wouldnt be such a bad idea. However graphics might be tricky, so I would rather rely on some test to support my analysis

Comment: My philosophical bias is generally to prefer graphics to tests, JMO.